# sqlite multithreading for single-thread mode with multiple databases

Tags: sqlite

The Sqlite Documentation say about multithreading

```
1. Single-thread. In this mode, all mutexes are disabled and SQLite is unsafe to use in more than a single thread at once.

2. Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads.

3. Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction.
```

I have a question about the 1(single-thread mode ). Does this say

1. It not allow to use sqlite3_open in two thread.
2. It not allow to use sqlite3_open to open the same database in two
   thread.But use   sqlite3_open to open two different database in two thread is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1.  If you want Option 2, you need to use multi-thread mode, exactly as the text says.  In single-threaded mode, the global state of the sqlite functions will not be protected, and using them simultaneously in multiple threads will be a problem.

With Multi-thread mode, you can use sqlite in multiple threads in the same application, but you may not share a single connection between threads simultaneously.